# iOS Application Crashing again and again when re-launching the application

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an iOS4 Application, sometimes if any crash happens in my application i am not able to launch my application it crashes again and again and not allow me to launch application for continuously 4 or 5 times.

This is my application log error code:

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x50000000

How to solve these kind of application crashes?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like you might try to access memory that's been already released or never actually allocated.

If you have no idea, where the crash is coming from, you have to work out bottom-up where the crash might occur. Disable all functionality of your app and gradually turn on until the crash comes up. That way you can isolate the memory issue you're having.

But first try running `Analyze` function in XCode - it may find potential problems you may be having in the code.